# Ruby REGEX for letters and numbers or letters followed by period, letters and numbers

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to construct a Ruby REGEX that will only allow the following:

```
some string (read letter only characters)
some string followed by numbers
some string followed by a period and another string
some string followed by a period and another string followed by numbers
period is only allowed if another string follows it
no other periods are allowed afterwards
numbers may only be at the very end
```

I have got `\A[[^0-9.]a-z]*([0-9]*|((.)([[^0-9]a-z]*)[0-9]*))\z` but I can't get what I need. This allows:

```
test.
test..
test.123
```

What is the correct REGEX? If someone could explain what I am doing wrong to help me understand for future that would be great too.

Edit: update requirements to be more descriptive

Comment: Explain what you want to pass and what you don't. Are you sure that you want the regex to match only the four strings that you listed?

Comment: is `test.test.test123` valid? is `test123test` valid? an so on.. it's unclear what you want.

Comment: In fairness to the guy... if they could specify what they wanted clearly, they probably wouldn't need to ask the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
^[a-z]+\.?[a-z]+[0-9]*$
```

Here is [demo](http://rubular.com/r/GXLWdcYiWs)

**Note:** use `\A` and `\z` to match starting and ending of string instead of line.

---

You need to escape `.` that matches any single character.

Pattern explanation:

```
  ^                        the beginning of the line
  [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more times)
  \.?                      '.' (optional)
  [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more times)
  [0-9]*                   any character of: '0' to '9' (0 or more times)
  $                        the end of the line
```

Comment: `^` and `$` are the beginning and end of a **line**, not a string.

Comment: yes I tried with `\A` and `\z` but why it's not working in the demo. I am not aware of ruby regex pattern. Please can you explain me.

Comment: Because you have multiple lines in your input, each of which is a testcase. If you use `\A` and `\z` then it will try and match all the test cases as one instance of the pattern, which they are not (The pattern does not allow newlines or any whitespace for one). But my point was that in your explanation you call `^` and `$` the beginning and of a *string* when they are the beginning and end of a line.

Comment: Thanks I got it. I placed all the words in new line in the demo that's why its not working. Thanks again. Let me update my post.

Comment: Great, thanks. I guess I was trying to be too complicated with my REGEX! It's good to see what I want to do working with an explanation why also so that I can learn for future.

Comment: This regex imposes a false limitation: That if there is only one string, it must be atleast two characters long. According to the description of the problem, the string "t1" should be accepted, but this regex will not accept it.

Answer (score 1):

<s>So I'm guessing you want `identifiers` separated by `.`.</s>

By `identifier` I mean:

- a string consisting of alphanumeric characters
- that does not start with a number
- and is atleast one characer long.

Written out as a grammar, it would look something like this:

```
EXPR  := IDENT "." EXPR | IDENT
IDENT := [A-Z]\w*
```

And the regex for this would be the following:

```
/\A[A-Z]\w*(\.[A-Z]\w*)*\Z/i
```

Try it out [here](http://rubular.com/r/xYHPbQ8d2H)

*Note* Due to the behaviour of `\w` this pattern will also accept `_` (underscores) after the first character (i.e. `test_123` will also pass).

**EDIT to reflect update of question**

So the grammar you want is actually like this:

```
EXPR  := IDENT [0-9]*
IDENT := STR | STR "." STR
STR   := [A-Z]+
```

And the regexp then is this:

```
/\A[A-Z]+(\.[A-Z]+)?[0-9]*\z/i
```

Try this one out [here](http://rubular.com/r/9ooM3MFvqS)

The explanation is as follows:

```
/            # start Regexp
  \A         # start of string
  [A-Z]+     # "some string"
  (          
    \.       # followed by a period
    [A-Z]+   # and another string
  )?         # period + another string is optional
  [0-9]*     # optional digits at the end
  \z         # end of string
/i           # this regexp is case insensitive.
```